# how to get tweet coordinates of users i am 'following'?

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I would like to get the coordinates of each member I am following on Twitter and place a pin on the map.

I am using twitter api https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json to retrieve all the info of users I am following. It does display their most recent tweet with their geo location.

But problem arises when they have not included their location while making a tweet and in that case I get a null in 'geo' field. 
I want their geo coordinates despite they have included their location or not.

I have been stuck for days finding solution. Please tell me if its possible. Do suggest any third party library.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: as you are using twitter api ...../friends/list.json which  Returns a cursored collection of user objects for every user the specified user is following (otherwise known as their “friends”).  for location u should use https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/search.json or https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/:place_id.json as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Himanshu thnx for ur reply bro, but these api's have nothing to do with what i have asked.

Comment: i was just trying to help sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

> But problem arises when they have not included their location while making a tweet and in that case I get a null in 'geo' field. I want their geo coordinates despite they have included their location or not.

If they don't want to share their location with you, there is nothing you can do.  If they haven't given a location to Twitter, then there is nothing that the API can return.